# the way that don`t need to add support library to make recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I'm annoyed because I do not always understand this problem.

If you always do searching, the support library is meant to be able to do new functions on older devices.

For example, Material Design was introduced in API 21 (Android 5.0 - Lolipop) but the v7 support library makes it available for API 7 (Android 2.1.x -Eclair) and higher.

Why does a .gradle file need v7 even though my app minSdk is 22?

I have seen that support library was created for a specific function also.

If you need a support library when using the recylcer view in API level 21 or later versions, virtually any version of the API needs a support library

To be honest, recycler view is used in all apps.

In version 21 or later, the recycler view should be able to be supported even if there is no support library by default I think

do I get wrong?
I wonder why they are not built-in.

I want you to let me know if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: `"I wonder why they are not built-in."` built-in where?

Comment: @pskink I mean if these things (support library) have prepared for less than version api level 21, should not it be possible to use without support library in version 21 or later?

Comment: this is how `Fragment`s and `VectorDrawable`s are implemented